# Haskell for Mac (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, haskell

I'm trying to decide what haskell installation is more appropriate for a Mac running El Capitan.

It seems there are at least two alternatives:

- Install the haskell platform as indicated in https://www.haskell.org/platform/
- Install the haskell platform as indicated in https://ghcformacosx.github.io/

What is the difference between the two distributions?

Will I be able to use Xcode as an Haskell IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main differences I see are:

Haskell for Mac OSX:

- is relocatable
- comes with `stack` pre-built

Haskell Platform:

- installs in /usr/local/bin (requires root access)
- comes with more pre-compiled libraries
- comes with the programs `happy` and `alex` pre-built

Neither comes with explicit support for using Xcode as an IDE. Usually one uses Emacs or Atom or Vi to develop Haskell programs.

Comment: May I ask what `stack` is?

Comment: Furthermore, what are the advantages and disadvantages, respectively, of the two distributions?

Comment: `stack` is a tool to help you manage dependencies and generate reproducible builds. More info [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/release/doc/GUIDE.md) and [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack). It serves somewhat the same function as `cabal`. In place of `cabal install ...` and `ghci` you generally can use `stack install ... ` and `stack ghci`.

Comment: It's not an either-or proposition. You can always download `stack` after installing the Haskell Platform. If you are a total beginner I think you'll find starting with the Haskell Platform easier - most tutorials and examples are written with the HP in mind. Once you gain more familiarity with cabal projects or if you start running into dependency issues you can switch over to `stack`.

Comment: Mmhh.. It seems that the official Haskell platform is the safe way.. I'm installing it for a Languages & Compilers university class, so probably I'll need stuff like `happy` and `alex`. Do you see any disadvantage about installing in `\usr\loca\bin`? May it mess with something?

Comment: /usr/local/bin is the standard location for user-installed Unix programs.

Comment: Mmhh, it seems all file have been installed in `\Library`, and executables just symlinked in `\usr\bin` (not `\usr\local\bin`). I guess all this is OK, however..

Comment: Something went awry. According to documentation, I should have the `ghc` command ready (due to symlinks). It is not so..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93877/discussion-between-erikr-and-madhatter).